# Magic Form in OctoberCMS

Tags: html, forms, content-management-system, octobercms

I've being trying to edit some fields in the Magic Form plugin in OctoberCMS, but i'm facing some dificulties. I want to change the "recipient" that is going to receive all the information on the form in his email. But everytime i open the field "recipient", it has this html code inside. Heres a print showing it:[image]

"Destinatários" is the portuguese translation for "Recipient", where i should be able to write down an email, and should be good to go. However, everytime i open it, it has the same code inside, doesn't matter if i delete it.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue you need to change `core OctoberCMS file`

Source : https://tutorialmeta.com/october-cms/magic-forms-octobercms-bug-fix-solution

> **modules\system\assets\ui\storm-min.js** (approx line no: **5808**)

**Before**
[image]

**After**
[image]

**This**

```
<textarea class="form-control size-small field-textarea" name="name">
</textarea>
```

**To This**

```
<textarea class="form-control size-small field-textarea" name="name" value=""/>
```

**It will fix your issue**

if you have any doubt please comment.

Comment: I just open'd this file, and this modification has already been made, i'm working in another person's code, it's writen like this:
```
<p class="inspector-field-comment"></p>                                         \
<textarea class="form-control size-small field-textarea" name="name" value=""/>```

Comment: hmm without source code I can not debug and find bugs. as the above solution was so far worked for me.

Comment: I opened the source code, this modification has already been made :(

Comment: maybe if it is browser related bug you can reverse the step from the answer and check if it's working or not ?

Comment: hmm not sure what could be an issue then, without code I can not debug it :(

Comment: that's ok, thank you for your help!!!!! double thanks for remembering this question haha!

Comment: sorry, but i forgot to tell you that it actually worked!!! huge thanks man!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove that html and add the email addresses you want (each address on a new line)

Comment: I can't do that, everytime i delete the HTML, write the email and save it, the HTML code just comes back, and everything that i wrote is gone..

Comment: Show the html code where the feedback form component is connected

Comment: i didn't understand what you asked, if you're asking about the HTML that renders the form, it's just a regular form with nothing special, but then i add a component that "handles" all the data collected from the form, and there is a print showing this component in the question